# Connect AWS Redshift cluster created in VPC A from VPC B

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, transit-gateway

I have created an AWS Redshift cluster in VPC A in account 1234567890 and a transit Gateway in another AWS Account 9876543210. I want to access redshift cluster from VPC B in same account where VPC A is present 1234567890.
I have updated the route tables of VPC A and VPC B and gave destination as IP of each vpc with target as this TGW ID created in another account.
[image]
[image]
Now, I am trying to access redshift cluster from VPC B but getting:

```
root@abc (VPCB) ~ $ psql -h abc-redshift-rs.lllvvvfpy07m.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com -p 5432
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "abc-redshift-rs.lllvvvfpy07m.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com" (10.148.1.98) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Also allowed 5432 port tcp connection from IP 10.0.0.0/8.
[image]
Can someone please guide me what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you checked the redshift cluster security group setting?